# Using WHILE LOOP to insert into Junction Table

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm using the following query to insert into a JunctionTable that is used to match 2 tables (Listing & Categories) for a sort of yellowpages directory.

Any given Listing can be attributed 1 or more categories.

The following query is inserting 3 records into my Junction table with 1 problem. I have 3 fields (ID,Junc_LID,Junc_CatID) representative of the ID columns in my two other tables LID being Listing ID and CatID being the Category ID.

Running the query is adding 3 records with 1,2,43,34 in the CatID field rather than inserting 4 times each with a different catID.

**So if a user select 10 categories from my web-form. The query should loop 10 times inserting 10 rows into my JunctionTable 1 for each category the user selects. Inputting 1 CatID per insert rather than a string of all the categories comma delimited as it's doing now.**

[image]

```
DECLARE @cnt INT = 0;

WHILE @cnt < 3
BEGIN
INSERT INTO BND_ListingJunction_testing (Junc_LID,Junc_CatID)
Values ('[PulledLID]','[CatID]') 
SET @cnt = @cnt + 1;
END;
```

--------------------------------------UPDATE

Here is your query modified for my tokens. It does work but adds some additional inserts into my junction table that I have not idea where they are coming from.

```
DECLARE @CatIDStr VARCHAR(100) = '[CatID]',@CatID VARCHAR(100) = ''

WHILE LEN(@CatIDStr) > 0
BEGIN

   IF CHARINDEX(',',@CatIDStr) = 0
   BEGIN
      SET @CatID = @CatIDStr
      SET @CatIDStr = ''
   END  
   ELSE
   BEGIN
     SELECT @CatID = SUBSTRING(@CatIDStr,0,CHARINDEX(',',@CatIDStr))                                        
     SELECT @CatIDStr=SUBSTRING(@CatIDStr,CHARINDEX(',',@CatIDStr)+1,LEN(@CatIDStr))
   END

   INSERT INTO BND_ListingJunction_testing (Junc_LID,Junc_CatID)
   Values ('[ScopedLID]',@CatID) 

END
```

[image]

Rows 1-7 are all from the same insert executed only once.

Comment: Your question isn't clear enough.

Comment: I've added some text in bold clarifying my intentions.

Comment: @AlexP Show sample data please.

Comment: Parse your input string and process the output.

Comment: @IvanStarostin I'm sorry Ivan could you give me a bit more details. I'm still learning TSQL.

Comment: @NEER I've included a screenshot of the data in sql, what else could I show?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
  DECLARE @CatIDStr VARCHAR(100) = '1,2,43,34',@CatID VARCHAR(100) = ''
  DECLARE @PulledLID INT = 1
WHILE LEN(@CatIDStr) > 0
BEGIN

   IF CHARINDEX(',',@CatIDStr) = 0
   BEGIN
      SET @CatID = @CatIDStr
      SET @CatIDStr = ''
   END  
   ELSE
   BEGIN
     SELECT @CatID = SUBSTRING(@CatIDStr,0,CHARINDEX(',',@CatIDStr))                                        
     SELECT @CatIDStr=SUBSTRING(@CatIDStr,CHARINDEX(',',@CatIDStr)+1,LEN(@CatIDStr))
   END

   INSERT INTO BND_ListingJunction_testing (Junc_LID,Junc_CatID)
   Values (@PulledLID,@CatID) 

END
```

Comment: this example does work but also for some reason is always adding ( [PulledLID],1 & [PulledLID],2 & [PulledLID],43 & [PulledLID],34 ) into the table in addition to the correct values i've chosen. I modified the form and changed the token value of [PulledLID] to [ScopedLID] and changed '1,2,43,34' at the DECLARE to [CatID] a token so i'm not sure  where it's adding those 4 values from?

Comment: Clearly tell what you change and what your expected result or give some example

Comment: I've updated my post with new screenshot & info. Basically I've replaced [PulledLID] with [ScopedLID] yet when I run the query it still inserts the same original 4 rows and then the proper data below. Screenshot depicts what I mean.

Comment: what value you want insert in Junc_LID

Comment: So i'm running another insert statement previous to this one so I need the PK of that insert into Junc_LID. I'm using `select scope_identity()` to grab this ID storing it in a token, which is [ScopedLID] and then running this query.